# Adjective form of "integrity"

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives, synonyms

> I have become a more honest person.

Is there a way in which I can replace the word *honest* in the above sentence with an adjective with the same root as *integrity*?

Comment: _I have improved my integrity_. In Danish you could have said _I have become a more integer person_ but that does not work in English

Comment: Nouns do not have tenses, adjectives cannot be conjugated, and a form is not a spelling. I have edited the question accordingly. Please take notice.

Comment: @RegDwigнt apologies I was trying to think of the right terms to use that was the best I had thanks for the edit.